# Axiom throwing error for Axis2 generated WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, axiom

I have auto generated classes from a WSDL file using Axis2 `wsdl2java` script. After adding the generated Java files to a Maven project the dependencies were only `axis2-adb` and `axis2-kernel`. However during runtime it is throwing the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/util/UIDGenerator
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation.<init>(AxisOperation.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation.<init>(AxisOperation.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.TwoChannelAxisOperation.<init>(TwoChannelAxisOperation.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation.<init>(OutInAxisOperation.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.<init>(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:47)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.Stub.addAnonymousOperations(Stub.java:233)
    at com.tobeprecise.sms.webservices.HttpReceiverStub.populateAxisService(HttpReceiverStub.java:42)
    at com.tobeprecise.sms.webservices.HttpReceiverStub.<init>(HttpReceiverStub.java:184)
    at com.tobeprecise.sms.webservices.HttpReceiverStub.<init>(HttpReceiverStub.java:173)
    at com.tobeprecise.sms.webservices.HttpReceiverStub.<init>(HttpReceiverStub.java:222)
    at com.tobeprecise.sms.webservices.HttpReceiverStub.<init>(HttpReceiverStub.java:214)
    at in.capillary.nsadmin.gateway.tobeprecisebulk.TobepreciseBulkGatewayChannel.sendMessages(TobepreciseBulkGatewayChannel.java:122)
    at in.capillary.nsadmin.gateway.BufferedGatewayChannelProcessor.process(BufferedGatewayChannelProcessor.java:150)
    at in.capillary.nsadmin.gateway.BaseGateway.process(BaseGateway.java:207)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    ... 18 more
```

While looking at the dependencies I have found the `axiom-api-1.2.11` as a dependency and it very well contains the **UIDGenerator** class. Is this due to version mismatch?

Found a similar issue [ClassNotFoundException axiom-api-1.2.7.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555447/classnotfoundexception-axiom-api-1-2-7-jar) but I coudn't make much sense out of it(my manifest file: http://pastebin.com/n4jKWPck). Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that the `axiom-api-1.2.1` is in your classpath at runtime?

Comment: Are you using Maven, Ant, or something else?

Comment: How do I ensure that. I am using the wsdl generated file and pushing the jar to my local and using its methods in another project.